# why isn't the square drawing when i type 1 or 2?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

here's the code but I don't know why it doesn't work I've tried adding a revalidate and a repaint but the square won't draw, I'm trying to make the square move over a bit when 2 is entered and the 1 is there as an attempt to force a refresh and draw the square but it never worked unless i just have the square be still but as said i want it to move

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(new DrawSquare());
        System.out.println("end");
        while (true==true){
        frame.revalidate();
        System.out.println("should work");
    }
}
}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;




public class DrawSquare extends JPanel {
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.red);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Integer x = 90;
        Integer y = 0;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
       
        while (y==0){
        
        
        
        while (true){
            frame.revalidate();
            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter command 1=draw square 2= move square");

    Integer input = myObj.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Next step: " + input);
    if(input == 2){
        x=x+1;
        input = 3;
    } 
    if(input == 1 ){
    
        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.red);
        g.drawRect(x, x, x, x);
        g.fillRect(x,x,x,x);  
        frame.repaint();
        frame.revalidate();
        System.out.println("WHY");
     break;
    }
            g.setColor(java.awt.Color.red);
            g.drawRect(100, x, 100, 100);
            g.fillRect(100,x,100,100);  
            System.out.println("sqlaie");
            
           
            frame.revalidate();
           

          
}
            
    }


    }

    }
```

Comment: Get rid of `while (true==true){` it's not doing what you think it's doing. `while (true==true){` within the `paintComponent` method is going to cause your program to hand and no longer be responsive. I have no idea why you're creating a new frame here and you should not be using `Scanner` to get user input from within a GUI.  So, the basic answer to your question is - because that's not how it' done

Comment: I would highly recommend taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to get a better understanding of how the paint system works and [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/misc/keybinding.html) for details about how to monitor and respond to user input

Answer (score 2):

First...

```
while (true==true){
    frame.revalidate();
    System.out.println("should work");
}
```

No it shouldn't (work).  Free cycling loops like this are capable of consuming all you CPU cycles which could prevent your program from performing other tasks (ie thread starvation).  `revalidate` won't repaint the UI anyway, it's used to update the layout of the components within a given container.

Then...

```
g.setColor(java.awt.Color.red);
super.paintComponent(g);
```

`paintComponent` will set the color of the `Graphics` to the background color of the component, which means that your previous call will be undone.  Call `paintComponent` first, then perform your custom painting.

Then...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //...
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
```

Ah, why?  Apart from create another `frame` each time `paintComponent` is been called, this has nothing to do with what's been presented on the screen and is otherwise just a complete waste of time and resources.

And then...

```
while (y == 0) {
    while (true) {
        frame.revalidate();
        //...
```

This is going to cause your program to hang, prevent any further updates to the UI and user input being captured.

`paintComponent` is expected to paint the current state and exit as fast as possible, you should avoid doing extra processing which could otherwise be done else where.

and finally...

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Don't use `Scanner` for user input in a GUI environment, this isn't how user input is monitored for.

Everything speaks volumes of your lack of understanding and appropriate research into how to solve these problems.

Stackoverflow is not a tutorial site and you should spend the time researching your problems and attempting to fix them before posting.  Once you've reached this point, SO becomes useful to you.

I would highly recommend taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to get a better understanding of how the paint system works and [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/misc/keybinding.html) for details about how to monitor and respond to user input

I would avoid `KeyListener` as it's problematic.

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int x = 90;
        private int y = 90;

        public TestPane() {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "pressed.one");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, 0), "pressed.two");

            am.put("pressed.one", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Really, kind of pointless here
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            am.put("pressed.two", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    x += 5;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```